# Nato Alphabet program in Python

Tags: python, list, input

I wrote a program that takes your inputs saves them in a list and converts them to the nato phonetic alphabet equivalent however it only works on the first list index if i do more than one input I can't figure out whats wrong with my loop

```
from pickle import FALSE
# Two lists one for nato the other for letters

import sys
nato= ["alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta", "echo", "fox-trot", "golf", "hotel", "india","juliet", "kilo", "lima", "mike", "november", "oscar", "papa", "quebec", "romeo", "sierra", "tango", "uniform", "victor", "whiskey", "x-ray", "yankee", "zulu" ]
alphabet = ['a','b','c', 'd', 'e','f','g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

# enter input in words or letters

user_input = input('Enter any word or letter: ').casefold() # if the user enters a capital letter

list =[]

list.append(user_input)

print("Continue?: ")

answer = input("y or n: ")
if answer == "y":
  answer=True
elif answer =="n":
  answer=False
  print(list)
while bool(answer) == True:
  user_input = input('Enter any word or letter: ').casefold() # if the user enters a capital letter

  list.append(user_input)

  print("Continue?: ")
  answer = input("y or n: ")
  if answer == "y":
    answer=True
  elif answer =="n":
    answer=False
   # print(list)
    break


for x in range(len(list)):
  x=0
  list[x]=list[x][0]
  for n in range(26):
    if list[x]==alphabet[n]:
      list[x]=nato[n]
  x+=1
print(list)
```

Enter any word or letter: jhkhjk
Continue?:
y or n: y
Enter any word or letter: sdfg
Continue?:
y or n: n
['juliet', 'sdfg']

that should say juliet, sierra

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it's a built-in type.

Comment: you need to loop over all the characters in `list[x]`, not just process `list[x][0]`.

Comment: Don't use two lists for `alphabet` and `nato`. Use a dictionary that maps from letters to nato.

Comment: And if you do use lists, you can use `alphabet.find()` to get the index, instead of writing your own `for` loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Comment: Aside, your whole `answer == "y"` thing is convoluted and doesn't even cover all cases. If I enter "blarg", that isn't matched by either check and `answer` will be neither `True` nor `False`, but "blarg" will act as truthy in `while bool(answer) == True` anyway. You can condense all that to just `answer = input("y or n: ") == "y"`. `answer` is then `True` if and only if I entered "y", and in no other case. Then `while answer:` will suffice as well. For a more complete handling of such cases, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23294659/476.

Comment: Think carefully about the logic of the code. Where it says `for x in range(len(list)):`, exactly what do you think this means? What will happen to `x` at the beginning of each loop? What is the intended purpose of doing that? Now, look at the next line of the code. What does it say? Do you see how that would cause a problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to change the for loop printing the entries:

```
for x in range(len(list)):
  list[x]=list[x][0]
  for n in range(26):
    if list[x]==alphabet[n]:
      list[x]=nato[n]
print(list)
```

As pointed out the problem is the line `x=0` resetting the counter

Comment: This is wrong, and demonstrates a fundamental misunderstanding of how loops work in Python. While the `x += 1` in OP's code is not *necessary*, its effect would simply be overridden by the normal operation of the loop. `range` is **not special syntax**; it is **just** a way to make an iterable sequence of values. A `for` loop is **not** mere syntactic sugar over a `while` loop; it actually sets the "counter" to values that are taken from the iterable input, and is limited by the **length of that input, not** any arithmetic condition.

Comment: Rather, the problem is the `x=0` at the **top** of the loop.

Comment: Yeah you're right didn't know an increment doesn't effect the counter variable, I'm more used to C where it has an effect.

Comment: I took the increment out and it worked I'm used to Java that's all

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned previously, you should not use `list` as a variable name. While you can technically use `list` as a variable name, it's strongly discouraged and considered bad practice. The reason for this is that `list` is a built-in data type in Python

Also, in your case, a dictionary seems to be a more suitable data structure:

```
# Define a dictionary to map letters to NATO phonetic alphabet words
nato_dict = {
    'a': 'alpha', 'b': 'bravo', 'c': 'charlie', 'd': 'delta', 'e': 'echo',
    'f': 'fox-trot', 'g': 'golf', 'h': 'hotel', 'i': 'india', 'j': 'juliet',
    'k': 'kilo', 'l': 'lima', 'm': 'mike', 'n': 'november', 'o': 'oscar',
    'p': 'papa', 'q': 'quebec', 'r': 'romeo', 's': 'sierra', 't': 'tango',
    'u': 'uniform', 'v': 'victor', 'w': 'whiskey', 'x': 'x-ray',
    'y': 'yankee', 'z': 'zulu'
}

# Initialize an empty list to store the NATO phonetic alphabet words
nato_list = []

# Take user input
while True:
    user_input = input('Enter any word or letter: ').casefold()
    
    # Check if the input is not empty and is a letter
    if user_input and user_input[0].isalpha():
        # Get the first letter of the user input
        first_letter = user_input[0]
        # Find corresponding NATO phonetic alphabet word
        nato_word = nato_dict.get(first_letter)   
        # Append the result to the list
        nato_list.append(nato_word)

    # Ask if the user wants to continue
    answer = input("Continue (y/n): ").strip().lower()
    if answer != "y":
        break

# Print the NATO phonetic alphabet words
print(nato_list)
```

If you're curious how you might achieve the same result using two lists, here is an example:

```
# Define lists to store letters and their corresponding NATO phonetic alphabet words
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
nato_words = ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta', 'echo', 'fox-trot', 'golf', 'hotel', 'india', 'juliet', 'kilo', 'lima', 'mike', 'november', 'oscar', 'papa', 'quebec', 'romeo', 'sierra', 'tango', 'uniform', 'victor', 'whiskey', 'x-ray', 'yankee', 'zulu']

# Initialize an empty list to store the NATO phonetic alphabet words
nato_list = []

# Take user input
while True:
    user_input = input('Enter any word or letter: ').casefold()
    
    # Check if the input is not empty and is a letter
    if user_input and user_input[0].isalpha():
        # Get the first letter of the user input
        first_letter = user_input[0]
        
        # Find the index of the letter in the 'letters' list
        index = letters.index(first_letter)
        
        # Find corresponding NATO phonetic alphabet word from the 'nato_words' list using the same index
        nato_word = nato_words[index]
        
        # Append the result to the list
        nato_list.append(nato_word)

    # Ask if the user wants to continue
    answer = input("Continue (y/n): ").strip().lower()
    if answer != "y":
        break

# Print the NATO phonetic alphabet words
print(nato_list)
```

Comment: This doesn't address the actual error, which is a typo. Please read [answer] and keep in mind that we don't do code review here, and expect the OP to attempt standard debugging steps first in order to obtain a proper [mre] of the code *that is actually causing the problem*.